# React table vertical scroll bar position

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-data-grid to paint the data in table format.Problem I am facing is if I scroll the table vertically and refresh the screen scroll bar is going to the top.How to set the vertical scroll bar position.I have attached the pic of component[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PHn4.png)

Comment: You want to save the scroll. bar position? could you give us more context on what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: You are right I want to store the scroll bar position of the table. the package I am using is react-data-grid. Let's say I scroll the table and refresh the page it's taking me to the top of the table but I want to persist the same scroll bar position which I had when I refreshed the page